# What is an easy way to mirror a template?

Tags: html, css, translation

English pages from [left to right](http://www.intel.com/?en_EG_01),  however Arabic is from [right to left](http://www.intel.com/?ar_EG_01).    What are some easy ways that you can change the CSS+HTML of a template such that it is best suited for Arabic?

Comment: I haven't done so myself, but you can look into: http://code.google.com/p/cssjanus/

Comment: @Russell Dias  that is an unfortunate name for what looks like a useful project.  Thanks.

Comment: @Russell Dias I'm pretty sure thats the right answer.  If you post it i'll award it to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this as an answer as requested :)

Lo' and behold [cssjanus](http://code.google.com/p/cssjanus).